# Not getting system Name on Global machine.

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted a website using IIS. For a button click i have given a code to fetch the System's name to a label. Below is the code-

```
protected string GetIP1(){
string strHostName = "";
strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
return strHostName;}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
Label3.Text = "Computer Name: " + GetIP1();
}
```

I am able to get the name when i am using it on my local system but when i am hosting it using IIS and opening link on another system, its giving me the same system name not the machine name on which it is running.

Comment: Can you give an example for "its giving me the same system name not the machine name" and what your expectation is? You are asking for the server name, not the client, right?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: Suppose, if there are 100 people connected to the particular network. I have hosted the website on my local system( using IIS). I have shared a link of this website for everyone so they can go and check their details. There on one button click i have given THIS CODE. The problem is when they access this website on their system and click that particular button to get system name, it shows my system name not their system name.

Comment: The code you gave runs on the server. So it is expected, that it always shows your system name.

Comment: Is there a way to get the system name on which this website runs?

Comment: Not from server-side asp.net code. And I guess that information is not accessible from the JavaScript sandbox either.